# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Tags: django, nginx

I had website which is running using Django and it is working using nginx.

I had tried to install SSL on the website, but it didn't  succeed.

But now when I try to access the website , it is giving me this error:

502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

What should I do ?

thank you

Comment: At a time like this, you need logging to tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: Could you please show your nginx config?

Comment: user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
 worker_connections 1024;
 accept_mutex off;
}

http {
 server_tokens off;

 include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
 
 access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
 
 client_max_body_size 0;



include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include    /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;


server {
 listen 80;
 server_name beirutevictions.org;

 fastcgi_hide_header Set-Cookie;
 gzip on;
 gzip_comp_level    5;
    gzip_min_length    256;
     gzip_proxied       any;
     gzip_vary          on;

Comment: location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $HTTP_HOST;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $REMOTE_ADDR;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
    }

  }#
}